# How to monitor internet connectivity for a Windows application (EXE file)

Tags: windows, windows-8, monitoring

If I have an application being executed how can I then monitor exactly what internet connectivity it makes (if any)?

Currently I have an application with only one EXE file in it but ideally I want the monitoring program being able to grap any connectivity from whatever that EXE file starts up.

The reason is that I sometimes receives untrusted EXE files and I need to make sure they do not make suspicious connectivity to the internet. Note that I need to choose an EXE file to monitor *prior* to starting it up so I can catch any connectivity done in the startup of the application.

Comment: What about using Fiddler (google it)

Comment: @kroonwijk Fiddler captures http traffic from well-behaved applications that respect proxy settings.  This isn't much use for monitoring untrusted apps.  You can configure the Windows firewall to block outgoing traffic from untrusted apps.  You can monitor network traffic using Process Monitor or for much more detail use Network Monitor or the new Message Analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) or [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html). The only thing is that Fiddler blocks your browser from surfing and it slows your computer down while debugging. WireShark gives better performance, but a lot more information wich might be difficult to understand.

Comment: As @arx already said then Fiddler only graps HTTP(S) traffic. Wireshark doesn't care about applications/processes and only look in to network traffic.